# Sum of elements above secondary diagonal of matrix in C language

Tags: c

I had exam yesterday which asked me to write a program to find sum of elements above secondary diagonal (antidiagonal) of matrix in C language. I wrote the program which had 3 test cases and my program passed all of them but I only got half of points for this task. Below is my code. Can someone explain what is wrong here, my code or teacher?

program.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"


int main()
{
    int n,m;
    MATRIX *M;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    M=allocation(n);
    insert_elements(M);
    printf("Inserted matrix:\n");
    print(M);
    printf("RESULTS:\n");
    printf("%d", sum_above_diagonal(M));
    M=free_memory(M);
    
    return 0;
}
```

functions.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"

MATRIX* allocation(int n)
{
    int i,j;
    MATRIX* M;
    M= (MATRIX*)malloc(sizeof(MATRIX));
    
    M->n=n;
    
    
    M->mat=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
    
    if(M->mat== NULL){
        printf("Error during allocation of rows");
        return NULL;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        M->mat[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
        if(M->mat[i]== NULL){
            printf("Error during allocation of colums");
            return NULL;
        }
    }
        
    return M;
}


void print(MATRIX* M)
{   
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<M->n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<M->n;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",M->mat[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}

MATRIX* free_memory(MATRIX* M) {
    
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < M->n; i++){
        free(M->mat[i]);
    }
    free(M->mat);
    return NULL;
    
}

void insert_elements(MATRIX* M){
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < M->n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < M->n; j++){
            scanf("%d", &M->mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int sum_above_diagonal(MATRIX* M){
    int i,j, sum = 0;
    int n = M->n - 1;
    for(i = 0; i < M->n - 1; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            sum += M->mat[i][j];
        }
        n--;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

header.h

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

typedef struct matrix{
    int n;
    int** mat;
}MATRIX;

MATRIX* allocation(int n);
void print(MATRIX* M);
MATRIX* free_memory(MATRIX* M);

void insert_elements(MATRIX* M);
int sum_above_diagonal(MATRIX* M);

#endif
```

Code written is above

Comment: Did you ask your teacher?

Comment: Tomorrow I am going to see her. Problem is she is well known for incorrectly giving points to students. I asked to confirm my program works and to get some arguments in case she says it doesnt work.

Comment: Was it a functional thing, or a code style thing? Are you responsible for checking for invalid inputs, like a negative-size matrix?

Comment: It's worth noting your `main()` has `m` which is never used, so that could be a case for points off.

Comment: Exam works this way, they give you skeleton of program meaning all function are declared you just need to finish code within curly braces. Points are assigned proportionally to test cases passed. Mine had 3 and all of them passed.

Comment: If tasks asks you for certain input then I am responsible for checking invalid input. This one did not have that kind of constrain. You could enter any number but I am not sure about negative-size matrix. That could be it. Thanks

Comment: Not too serious: file "header.h" uses _header guard_ token `FUNCTIONS_H`... Unconventional and will cause an issue when file "functions.h" is added to project. Who wrote (or named) "header.h"?

Comment: @Fe2O3 professor named it

Comment: Then, who _wrote_ it? As said, it's not too serious in a tiny project like this, but the header guard token has an unconventional name.

Comment: @Fe203 professor wrote it and named it. I only had to add two prototypes for functions insert_elements and sum_above_diagonal. They taught us to always name header gurad token same as functions file

Comment: Three times you test the return from `malloc()` (good!) and may return NULL. Unfortunately, if an allocation fails, there's no "clean up" of previously successful allocations. Your `main()` will continue as if all is wonderful in the world... And, there's no verification that `scanf()` assigns the expected values... And, _casting_ the return from `malloc()` is a bad practice. Casting is unnecessary and can lead to future problems when code is modified.

Comment: @Fe203 why is casting from malloc() a bad practice? How is compiler then supposed to know what kind of data to write/read? What am I supposed to do instead?

Comment: `malloc()` returns a `void *` that can be assigned to any pointer type (without casting). To explicitly use casting is to override the compiler's knowledge of the datatypes involved. This will bite you one day. (Besides, less code is less to read and provides less opportunity for bugs to materialise.) What you've written is not _wrong_ but unnecessary and doesn't demonstrate confidence in understanding C.

Answer (score 2):

So, after clarification, there is no problem with what you compute exactly.
But there are still some C problem in the code.

1. The `allocation` function does allocate `M` a `MATRIX` structure, then `M->mat`, an array of rows (array of array), then `n` `M->mat[i]`, that is n rows. But the `free_memory` function does free only all `M->mat[i]` then `M->mat`, but not `M` itself.

Both can be a valid choice. One could except `allocation` function to work on already allocated structure (structure that could even be directly in the stack). Then, it would be normal that `free_memory` only frees the data, but let the caller responsible of the destruction of the structure itself. But then, it should have been also the case for `allocation`, that should have worked with a `M` whose pointer is passed as a parameter.

Or, if `allocation` stays as is, and allocate structure `M`, and then all needed data of `M`, `free_memory` should have also handled the disallocation of `M`.

Because as is, the caller of `allocation` (imagine that the library is used by external user, who sees only `header.h` and some compiled `libfunctions.so` but not `functions.c`) is not supposed to be aware how `M` was build (that is internal of `allocation`), and if it was obtained by a malloc or some other way.

A rule of thumb is that the one that does a `malloc` is also the one that does the `free`.

I personally dislike dogma when they become canned thinking. It more important to understand the reason behind a dogma rather than the dogma itself. So no "rule of thumb" is sacred, and there are cases where a libray does a `malloc`, and state in its documentation that caller is responsible for the matching `free`. But, well, even if I dislike dogma, I admit that you need at least a good reason to infringe them. And here you have none to break the rule "the one that does the malloc does the free". As author of the `functions` library you did the malloc in `allocations`, you should have done the matching `free` in the `free_memory`.

And, well, even without playing this role game (where you are both the author of a library and the user of it), what is certain is that in your code, `M` was never freed.

2. As I also said in comment, I find strange to return a `MATRIX *` in `free_memory`. What for? What matrix could be returned? Anyway, you return only NULL unconditionally anyway.

The second point is quite minor. The first is not, at least if the point is to judge the overall C program, not just the algorithmic part.

### Former answer

(but I've failed to understand that this was exactly what was asked for: sum of elements above anti-diagonal, aka secondary diagonal).

This doesn't sum the element above diagonal. It sums all elements above anti-diagonal.

In a matrix

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

Your code is suming 1+2+3 (in the first row) +5+6 (in the second) +9 (in the third) and then you skip the last row (Correctly so. And if you hadn't skipped it, it would have been an empty one any way).

But what was asked for was to sum 2+3+4 (in the first row) + 7+8 (in the second, +12 in the third (and still nothing in the last).

So result 36, not 26.

Code wise, it can be done by starting j at i+1 instead of 0 (`for(j=i+1; j<M->n; j++)`). And then no need for a decreasing n. The the number of iterations in this loop is already `M->n-1` the first time (when i=0, that is from i+1=1 included to `M->n` excluded, so, `M->n-1`), and then 1 less at each row, since `i` is 1 more.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but it is not supposed to check last row because it asks for sum ABOVE secondary diagonal. First element in last row is ON secondary diagonal therefor it is not added to sum of elements. First element of last row is on secondary diagonal and the rest of elements in last row are under secondary diagonal. Also I had 3 test cases with different numbers in matrix, if this did not work none of those test would not have passed.

Comment: It is indeed not supposed to check the last row, because there is no chance to find elements above diagonal in the last row. But that is a necessary condition not a sufficient. No element of the last row are above diagonal, sure. But the reverse is not true neither: not all elements that are not in the last row are above diagonal

Comment: @Vedran: Oh, sorry, I misread the code, and missed the `n--` part. So your code is computing the sum of of elments that are above **antidiagonal**

Comment: I get what are you saying but that is why my nested for loop is formed like that. Every iteration go to one column less than previous.

Comment: @Vedran In a 3x3 matrix `1 2 3` `4 5 6` `7 8 9`, it sums 1+2+4. So a upper triangle, but the wrong one. It should sum 2+3+6

Comment: Yes, I use term secondary diagonal. Dont know if its correct.

Comment: I think you are referring to main diagonal, in that case you would be correct. I am looking for sum above antidiagonal which is formed by 1+2+3, 5+6 and 9.

Comment: @Vedran Oh, right again. I didn't know this vocabulary (I am math teach in engineering school. But not from an English speaking country, so, sometimes I a still discovering elementary vocabulary).

Comment: @Vedran Then, your code is working. And seem ok enough to me. But I am not your teacher, and I don't know what point she wants to make. Maybe that `n--` seemed a little bit obfuscating to her. Or may be she found strange to return a `MATRIX *` in fhe `free_memory` function, if it is to return NULL inconditionaly any way.

Comment: @Vedran Or maybe she doesn't like the fact that this `free_memory` function doesn't free also the matrix itself (after all, the allocation functions does n+2 malloc: one for the matrix, one for the array of rows, one for each n rows. And the `free_memory` does only n+1 `free` (1 for each n rows, then one for the array of rows `M->mat`. but none for `M` itself). A rule of thumb is that each `malloc` in your code should match a `free` (or at least that if it doesn't, you should know why and have a good reason).

Comment: tomorrow I am going to speak to her. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code, `Matrix` is a square matrix with a size `n` (as in n by n), and is allocated as an array of pointers to arrays of integers. So mathematically [1][1] to [n][n] are valid subscripts, mapping to [0][0] to [n-1][n-1] in C.

The diagonal you're working with is from (C indexes) [0][n-1] to [n-1][0]. Your code works, so maybe the marks are taken off for style or readability.

You could add comments, explaining how `n` is used, or you could compute `M->n - 1 - i` (or the variation below) each time instead of using `n` and `n--`. Sometimes intermediate variables make things clearer, like `const int max_idx = M->n - 1;` so you don't repeat that in the loops (makes the above `max_int - i` instead of `M->n - 1 - i`). There might be a value to declaring `i` and `j` in the `for()` loops where they are used, so they don't get used unexpectedly out of scope.

I'm just trying to think of any possibility here, I don't think there's anything actually wrong with what you've written. The teacher would be the only one who really knows.

Answer (score 1):

Compare this (your) piece of code

```
int n = M->n - 1;
for(i = 0; i < M->n - 1; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
        sum += M->mat[i][j];
    }
    n--;
}
```

with

```
int n = M->n - 1;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
        sum += M->mat[i][j];
    }
}
```

Although, technically both do the same, the second code does not modify the (constant) variable `n`. The second code, only uses the relation between rows (`i`) and columns (`j`), no need to introduce a new 'player'.

In other words, your code depends on a unnecessary third variable (`n`), whereas two would be enough (`i` and `j`).

Without `n` (let the compiler do the work)

```
for (i = 0; i < (M->n - 1); i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < (M->n - 1) - i; j++) {
        sum += M->mat[i][j];
    }
}
```

can't be done with your example.

Answer (score 1):

Comments and other answers may give you insight as to why you received only partial marks for your work.

Below is an implementation of only `allocation()` for you to study. (The teacher should have used `size_t` as the datatype of the argument.)

```
static void *safe_malloc( size_t sz, int ind ); // helper function known only in this file
    void *p = malloc( sz );
    if( p == NULL )
        printf( "malloc failed on step %d\n", ind );

    return p;
}

MATRIX *allocation( int dim ) { // should be size_t
    /* matrix object */
    MATRIX *m = safe_malloc( sizeof *m, 1 );
    if( m == NULL )
        return NULL;

    m->n = dim;
    /* array of row pointers */
    m->mat = safe_malloc( m->n * sizeof *m->mat, 2 );
    if( m->mat == NULL ) {
        free( m );
        return NULL;
    }

    /* arrays of column values */
    for( size_t i = 0; i < m->n; i++ ) {
        m->mat[ i ] = safe_malloc( m->n * sizeof *m->mat[ i ], 3 );
        if( m->mat[ i ] == NULL ) {
            while( i--)
                free( m->mat[ i ] );
            free( m->mat );
            free( m );
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return m;
}
```

1. Notice the absence of casting the return value from `malloc()`.
2. Allocate the size of the *object*, not the size of the *datatype*.
3. A *helper* function keeps code compact.
4. If subsequent allocations fail, clean up what has been allocated before returning.

Importantly, missing from your `main()`:

```
    M = allocation(n);
    if( M == NULL )
        /* error message and terminate */
```

Don't continue processing with a NULL pointer!

NB: User data is often corrupt and shouldn't be trusted. All calls to `scanf()` should verify the assignment of the supplied variable (addresses). Not doing this is a source of **many** SO questions.

Finally, verify that the user has at least a 2x2 matrix of data before proceeding. The teacher may be wondering what your code will do when given 1, 0 or a negative value for `n`. German expression: "*Trust is good. Verification is better!*"

---

If the task is only to calculate and print the sum, there's a simpler way to achieve this without a lot of palaver. Overengineering is expensive:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    scanf( "%d", &n );

    puts( "Matrix:" );

    int sum = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {
            int x;
            scanf( "%d", &x ); // read value
            printf( "%*d", 3 + 3*!(n-1-i-j), x ); // display value

            if( i + j < n - 1 ) // interesting value?
                sum += x; // then add to tally
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    printf( "RESULTS:\n" );
    printf( "%d\n", sum );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Matrix:
  1  2  3     4 // notice the isolation of the numbers of interest.
  5  6     7  8
  9    10 11 12
    13 14 15 16
RESULTS:
26
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether the marks you got come from automated testing failures, manual code review or both.

Here are some insights for you to study and improve your coding skills:

- the code is not properly formatted: the brace style is inconsistent, the `printf("\n");` line is misaligned, the spacing in `for(j=0;j<M->n;j++)` is inconsistent with that of `for(i = 0; i < M->n; i++){`...

  You might have lost points for breaking local style or coding rules. It may seem futile, but consistent style helps reading the code and allows both the reader and writer to spot problems quicker.
- `MATRIX* allocation(int n)` makes a lot of `malloc()` calls, some of which are not checked.  Furthermore, you do not free memory allocated so far in case of allocation failure.  Both of these problems may cost you points.
- casting the return value of `malloc` as `(MATRIX*)` is not required in C and may be considered error prone.  Local style rules might forbid it.
- `allocation` does not initialize the allocated matrix. It would be good style to initialize the matrix elements to zero, which you get almost for free by using `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`.
- `MATRIX* free_memory(MATRIX* M)` does not free the `MATRIX` structure pointed to by `M`, this is a memory leak in all cases.  You might also want to avoid undefined behavior if `M` is a null pointer.
- `void insert_elements(MATRIX* M)` does not check for `scanf()` conversion errors.  It is unclear what you should do in this case, but you should at least report the problem.
- `int sum_above_diagonal(MATRIX* M)` uses 3 loop variables: it is somewhat confusing.  Using just `i` and `j` and an expression for the inner loop test is more readable.
- `m` is unused in the `main()` function.

You should compile your code with all warnings enabled and fix them.

Here is a modified version:

**program.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"

int main(void) {
    int n;
    MATRIX *M;

    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid matrix size: %d\n", n);
        return 1;
    }
    
    M = allocation(n);
    if (M == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate %dx%d matrix\n", n, n);
        return 1;
    }
    insert_elements(M);
    printf("Inserted matrix:\n");
    print(M);
    printf("RESULTS:\n");
    printf("%d\n", sum_above_diagonal(M));
    M = free_memory(M);
    return 0;
}
```

**functions.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"

MATRIX *allocation(int n) {
    int i;
    MATRIX *M = malloc(sizeof(*M));
    int **mat = malloc(sizeof(*mat) * n);
    int *cells = calloc(sizeof(*cells), n * n);

    if (M == NULL || mat == NULL || cells == NULL) {
        free(cells);
        free(mat);
        free(M);
        return NULL;
    }
    M->n = n;
    M->mat = mat;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        M->mat[i] = &cells[i * n];
    }    
    return M;
}

void print(MATRIX *M) {   
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < M->n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M->n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", M->mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

MATRIX *free_memory(MATRIX *M) {
    if (M) {
        free(M->mat[0]);
        free(M->mat);
        free(M);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void insert_elements(MATRIX *M) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < M->n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M->n; j++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &M->mat[i][j]) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "error reading matrix element at %d,%d\n", i, j);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

int sum_above_diagonal(MATRIX *M) {
    int i, j, sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < M->n - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M->n - 1 - i; j++) {
            sum += M->mat[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```